# Android HttpURLConnection gives 400 error

Tags: android, ios, http

I have the below Android code, this gives a 400 error:

```
url = new URL(requestURL);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);

MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
String token = db.getLoginToken();
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

os.close();
int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
```

This code gives me a 400 response code. I am trying to duplicate our iOS apps code which is:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    NSString *authorization = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",token];
    [request setValue:authorization forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:professionalConnections]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

And works with no problem.

Why does the Android code cause a 400 error?

Comment: The problem is in the data you are sending, in this case the URL. See: [10 Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html): 10.4.1 400 Bad Request

The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax.

Comment: @Lorenzo edited, why does the android code with a 400 error, or how can i debug it further

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the Content-Type header

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Comment: still gives 400, is there a way i can see the http request before its sent, to check if it matches the iOS version